# typedef a templated class with arguments

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

For the needs of a large project, I need to typedef an object of a templated class, instanciated with arguments.

```
Foo< A, B, C > FooItem(bar1, bar2);
```

`FooItem` is the object, constructed with `bar1` and `bar2`.

Is there a way to typedef this object (it has to be re-used into another Template as a type) ?

Comment: `typedef Foo<A, B, C> my_foo;`? (Terminology nitpick: you cannot typedef objects)

Comment: you can't typedef an object, only a type. `typedef Foo< A, B, C > FooType; FooType FooItem (bar1, bar2);`

Comment: You could use a macro, but what's the point?  bar1 and bar2 might not be in scope at any point, so it's not a widely applicable macro.  If bar1 and bar2 are primitives you can always subclass your template and hardcode the values in.

Comment: @aleguna compiler now tells me `'FooType FooItem' redeclared as different kind of symbol` :/

Answer (score 2):

You can't typedef *objects*. You can typedef *types*. (The clue is in the name!)

For objects, you want *references* if you need a shorter handle:

```
typedef Foo<A, B, C> FooABC;

FooABC FooItem(bar1, bar2);

auto & f = FooItem;    // 'f' is a FooABC &

auto copy_of_f = f;    // this is a FooABC
```

Answer (score 0):

What about construct new class?

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct Foo1 : public Foo<T1,T2,T3>
{
    Foo1()
    : Foo<T1,T2,T3>(bar1, bar2)   //bar1, bar2 - global or static objects?
    {}
// ......       
};

Foo1<int, char, double> a;
//....
typedef Foo1<A,B,C>  FooItem;
FooItem b;
```